# How do filter/slicing in pandas work? Why always it occupies ram?

Tags: python, pandas

I've been doing data science for few years, but just right now I've realized that when I filter columns with any **any** method, it occupies RAM.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime

df = pd.DataFrame({'A' : ['spam', 'eggs', 'spam', 'eggs'] * 175000,
                   'B' : ['alpha', 'beta', 'gamma' , 'foo'] * 175000,
                   'C' : [np.random.choice(pd.date_range(datetime.datetime(2013,1,1),datetime.datetime(2013,1,3))) for i in range(700000)],
                   'D' : np.random.randn(700000),
                   'E' : np.random.random_integers(0,4,700000)})
```

Now run any of these methods a few times.

```
df.iloc[:, :4]

df.filter(regex="A|B|C|D")

df.loc[:, ["A", "B", "C", "D"]]

dft[["A", "B", "C", "D"]]

df[df["A"]=="spam"]
```

Every time you run it, the df is loaded in memmory and never released. Why? I'm just exploring a dataset, this should not happen.

Otherwise, these methods do not attempt against memory usage:

```
df.iloc[0:500000]

df.loc[:500000]
```

So it's kind like I use columns in the filtering criteria, then the df is stored in RAM. how am I supposed to do data exploration with large datasets?

Answer (score 2):

I think there is no correct answer to your question.

However to limit the memory size, you can make some modifications to your dataset:

- convert `A` and `B` columns as `category` dtype,
- downcast `D` column to convert `float64` to `float32`,
- reduce the internal storage of `datetime64` (`ns` to `ms` or `s`).

Now, if you make a copy (rather than a view) the subset dataframe will be smaller.

In data exploration phase (or not), you can enable [**copy on write** (CoW)](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/dev/user_guide/copy_on_write.html). There are plenty of [methods that are optimized](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/dev/user_guide/copy_on_write.html#copy-on-write-optimizations) for CoW.

As alternative, you can also try some other libraries like `PyArrow` (Pandas/PyArrow as `dtype_engine`) or `Polars` that can be more memory efficient.

Comment: thought of using pyarrow now that it available naively. However, here I do not think that copy on write applies, i'm not copying neither writing, I'm just printing a filtered df. Am I crazy or this behavior has no sense?